# How do I configure vim to unzip files with 7zip?

Tags: vimrc, microsoft-windows, plugin-zip

In an answer [to this particular question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6459051), it's said that it's enough to have unzip installed and available to make vim able to unzip files on the fly. However, I'm wondering if there's a way to configure vim so that it doesn't use unzip, but rather any arbitrary archiver (which, of course, may need to meet certain requirements).

In particular, I'm interested in whether it's possible to use 7zip on a Windows machine.

Comment: Have a look at `:h pi_zip.txt` and check especially for the `g:zip_unzipcmd` variable

Answer (score 1):

zipPlugin shipped with Vim is poorly customizable. All command-line flags are hardcoded and cannot be changed. So there won't be any nice solution. Except maybe patching plugin's source code, or writing some wrapper shell script to re-translate option flags etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question, but you can call an arbitrary executable when opening a zip file. I don't use Windows, but if I wanted to unzip files automatically on Linux, `dtrx -n` looks like a good option:

```
" ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/zip.vim 
call system("dtrx -n " . shellescape(expand("%:p"))) | :e %:p:r
```

You will be shown the contents of the zip file as usual in the unzipped directory. This assumes that your tool can work non-interactively and uses a directory with the same as your zip file.